# Pop view when tapping a button in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have an Iphone application in which i want to add a feture such that when the user tapp a button it will a popup view with some text on it. i need to have another text when he again tapped it.can anybody help me how to do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you want actually Have a look at UIAlertView and UIActionSheet classes.May be u r looking for this or elaborate more your problem

Comment: i want to show a ui view like a pop up view everytime when the user taps on the button.and i needs the text content of my uiview needs to be changed with each tap of the user

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a modal view like UIAlertView, but a view on top of the one which contains the button. This could be done with adding "Popup View" as subview of the other view.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to present a modal view controller. You would create a `UIViewController` to manage the view you want to "pop up". Then use `presentModalViewController:` to show the view.

```
YourPopUpViewController *vc = [[YourPopUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

To go back you implement the following code somewhere in `YourPopUpViewController`.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```